# CXF. Is it possible to log the request/response XML without using Interceptor?

Tags: cxf

I would like to get the request XML in my Web service method and would like to save it.  I know I can use LoggingInInterceptor to do that.  However, I do not want to use it. The reason is when I save the request XML, I would like to perform user validations, get the client name and use the client name as the File name to save it.

Is there a way I can get the request XML in my Web service method.

Comment: Last time I checked, the out-of-the-box, default CXF configuration will automatically log your XML request and response to SysOut.log

Comment: how is your saving request related to logginginterceptor ?

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot. But you can write a generic HTTP service which gets the text content of a request.